# Generic return type possible with Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring-aop

I tried to create Aspect using generic annotation like

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CommonAspect<T extends CommonEntity>{


    @AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(audit)",returning="retVal")
    public void save(JoinPoint jp,T retVal, Audit audit) {

        Audit audit = new Audit();
        audit.setMessage(retVal.getAuditMessage());
        //other code to store audit

    }


}
```

Is this possible ? it fail in my case. 
I want to use this @Audit annotation for person, user etc different kind of entity. so return value can be generic.

Comment: please elaborate more

Comment: Can you attach the full Aspect codes?

Comment: @LipingHuang added full aspect codes

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I want to use this Audit annotation for person, user etc different kind of entity. so return value can be generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're trying to define an aspect for methods that return `CommonEntity`.
In that case, you don't need to use generics, you can just remove the generic declaration and slightly adjust your aspect declaration:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CommonAspect {


    @AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(audit) && execution(CommonEntity *(..))",returning="retVal")
    public void save(JoinPoint jp, CommonEntity retVal, Audit audit) {

        Audit auditInfo = new Audit();
        auditInfo.setMessage(retVal.getAuditMessage());
        //other code to store audit

    }


}
```

What I've done is replace the `T` in the argument list and add `execution(CommonEntity *(..))` to the pointcut expression to limit the matching to pointcuts where a `CommonEntity` is returned.

Comment: Thanks. I did similar changes but still it could not recognize aspect. is it work if aspect defined in separate module.

Comment: It works with "execution(* *(..))  and CommonEntity paramter. thanks a lot for clue :)